# PyCharm и не отображаемые файлы

Tags: pycharm

Собственно, вопрос в том, как сделать файлы видимыми в проекте, например, такие как **pycache** и другие? Я знаю точно, что эта папка(**pycache**) присутствует в корне проекта.

Comment: В окне Project в выпадающем меню выберите "Project Files" - тогда будут видны все файлы проекта, если вы об этом

Comment: Хотелось видеть все файлы в окне Project. Сделал как вы сказали, но файлы __pycache__ не появились, хотя они точно присутствуют в папке проекта.

Comment: Проверьте в Settings -> Project:project name, что Content Root установлен верно, а также что в Exclude files снизу нет паттерна, который "прячет" нужные вам файлы

Comment: @cppquestions Конечно, спасибо, но Content Root по-моему установлен верно, паттернов нет, и все равно не отображаются все файлы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно удалить `__pycache__` из игнорируемых файлов в *Settings | Editor | File Types | Ignored files and folders*:

[image: Settings | Editor | File Types | Ignored files and folders]